# Is there an add-in that supports open file inside notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am looking for a feature so that I can open a file indicated by file name prefix inside notepad++.

For example,

```
// file.cpp

call_fun_a(..)

// call_fun_a.cpp
```

Assume both **file.cpp** and **call_fun_a.cpp** are in the same directory. when I highlight the **call_fun_a** then choose open file, I expect the notepad++ can open the **call_fun_a.cpp**. Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, recently somebody created the **[QuickOpen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickopenplugin/)** plug-in, which does exactly what you want.

> ..Just select the whole path and press alt+o, or use the button in the toolbar on top..
>
> ..The plugin understands the relative path..